# HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery - keep hover effect on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, click

To simplify my code, I have a container div. Inside the container div is an img and a form with some inputs. When you hover over the container div, the img fades away (using css to modify visibility), revealing the form.

What I essentially have is this:
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="/img/example.jpg"></div>
    <div class="form"><form>...</form></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
       opacity: 1;
       transition: ease 0.3s;
}
.container:hover .img {
       opacity: 0;  
    }
```

Once `.container:hover` is applied, if any part of `div.form form` is clicked, the `.container:hover` style is lost, i.e. the img fades back in and covers up the form. I am able to click on the form input boxes, but the img still fades in again. If I move my mouse, `.container:hover` is applied again and I can input my text into the box.

What I have noticed is that this only happens when I click using the built-in mouse buttons on my laptop. If I use my external mouse or a touchscreen device, this doesn't happen. I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I just want to be able to click on the form without the hover style being lost.

Comment: Not sure why that's the case, works on my desktop, but you're missing a closing `"` in the `img` tag and you should transition `opacity` instead of `visibility` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/rwjVqN

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Interesting. Would it be more helpful to look at the actual webpage with the full code? If so, the page is on http://www.rofordaward.co.uk/nominate.php

Comment: I used Chrome on my computer and this issue was observed. When I used Vivaldi, the form doesn't close when I click on the input in the form. If I click next to the input, the issue is observed again.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this:

```
#No2 {
visibility: hidden;
```

}

```
#No1:hover {
background: red;
```

}

```
#No1:hover + #No2 {
visibility: visible;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting cached data from your browser. Works miracles sometimes!!